# How to delete in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, delete-row

I want to delete one row from a matrx. However, tensorflow doesn't have module "delete" so if someone knows how to do it. Moreover, then I want to add a row in the matrix so if someone knows too, please. Thanks!

```
 MatrizDesnormalizada = tf.delete(MatrizDesnormalizada,indice,axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.gather` to do what you need. Following is a working example. Say you want to remove the `0th` row of a tensor with `3` rows of data.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]],[[2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5]],[[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6]]])

del_a = tf.gather(a, [1,2])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(del_a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works as np.delete for a matrix

```
def tf_delete(tensor,index,row=True):
    
    if row:
        sub = list(range(tensor.shape[0]))
    else:
        sub = list(range(tensor.shape[1]))
    sub.pop(index)
    
    if row:
        return  tf.gather(tensor,sub)
    return tf.transpose(tf.gather(tf.transpose(tensor),sub))
```

with row specifying if you want to delete a row or a column
example:

```
print(tensor)
tensor = tf_delete(tensor,1,row=True)
print(tensor)
tensor = tf_delete(tensor,1,row=False)
print(tensor)
```

return

```
tf.Tensor(
[[9. 5. 1. 3.]
 [9. 9. 6. 8.]
 [9. 9. 9. 2.]
 [9. 9. 9. 9.]], shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[9. 5. 1. 3.]
 [9. 9. 9. 2.]
 [9. 9. 9. 9.]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[9. 1. 3.]
 [9. 9. 2.]
 [9. 9. 9.]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```